# Mongoose Query Slow when using Defaults and Nested Objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a User doucment which contains many layers of nested objects pertaining to components on a page.

```
"featuredImage": {
                    "config": {
                        "style": {
                            "margin": {
                                "right": 0,
                                "left": 0,
                                "top": 0,
                                "bottom": 30
                            },
                            "background": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"
                        },
                        "class": "ss-article-featured-image"
                    }
                },
                "info": {
                    "date": {
                        "config": {
                            "style": {
                                "margin": {
                                    "right": 5,
                                    "left": 5,
                                    "top": 0,
                                    "bottom": 0
                                },
                                "fontWeight": "normal",
                                "fontSize": 16,
                                "background": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
                                "color": "inherit"
                            },
                            "show": true,
                            "class": "ss-article-date"
                        }
                    },
...
...
```

There might be ~ 50 components (nested objects) on this user document (average document size 10kb).

I'm using Mongoose "defaults" to automatically fill things in (like 0's, or strings that aren't explicitly provided).

When I query for this user, the query is fast, I can just look it up by ID, but timing the result of the document ends up being > 10ms even for my localhost to local DB.
When I do this on Heroku (from my connected DB) it ends up taking ~30ms - 100ms.

When I use `lean()` the query is much much faster:  ~5ms

(FYI I'm just wrapping the query call in `console.time` to time it)

.lean() will clear the defaults, and I'm relying on defaults to render things, so it's not really an option.

Is there something about this document style that is causing such an overhead for Mongoose?  Is it the defaults?  Is it the fact that there are so many nested objects?  The document itself is not that large, and the average document size for my users is 10kb.

50ms for a `findById` lookup is atrocious. But it seems to be the "size" or "style" of the document that is causing an issue.  Again, the document is not big.

Can anyone shed some light, here?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to consider with large objects like yours (10K) and using defaults. Mongoose is heavy in such scenarios since it has to give you the mongoose models you defined in your schema after the results are retrieved from MongoDB deal with the defaults etc. For documents like yours that costs a lot!

This is why you see and used `lean()` since it [removes that overhead and returns just plain objects with no mongoose sugar around them](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean). This also costs you since you depend on the defaults.

Once suggestion would be to not return the full objects but just the fields you need. I would assume you almost never need the entire 10K document.

[Docs on how to select and return partial (specific fields only) result](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select)

Docs on how to update partial model which is [basically just using $set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/#Updating-$set)

Another suggestion although kind of radical would be to consider for cases like yours to step down to the mongoDB native driver and work with it since that would be significantly faster on large objects like yours in comparison to Mongoose.

Comment: For each user I need all the potential components that they could have customized, so I do need like 50 different components.  It's basically like a page editor where every component could have things changed like padding, margins, color, etc.  So I just want all of it.

I'm aware that .lean just returns the plain JSON object, but I'm confused as to why 10k is a large object and why defaults "cost a lot".  I'm aware how to project the results, and my updates are fantastically fast, but my reads are bad news.